# Hot module reload is not working on my nextjs app

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

I have a project based on nextjs. Oddly enough, the HMR is not working properly for my project. Every time I make changes I have to re run the process. I have attached details of my next config and package.json:

next.config:

```
const withSass = require("@zeit/next-sass");
const withCSS = require("@zeit/next-css");

module.exports = withCSS(
  withSass({
    webpack(config, options) {
      config.module.rules.push({
        test: /\.(eot|woff|woff2|ttf|svg|png|jpg|gif)$/,
        use: {
          loader: "url-loader",
          options: {
            limit: 100000,
          },
        },
      });

      return config;
    }
  })
);
```

package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "export": "next export"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@zeit/next-css": "^1.0.1",
    "@zeit/next-sass": "^1.0.1",
    "antd": "^3.26.8",
    "chartjs": "^0.3.24",
    "classnames": "^2.2.6",
    "draft-js": "^0.11.4",
    "isomorphic-unfetch": "^3.0.0",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "next": "^9.2.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.13.1",
    "react": "16.12.0",
    "react-dom": "16.12.0",
    "react-helmet": "^5.2.1",
    "react-markdown": "^4.3.1",
    "react-mde": "^8.1.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.0",
    "react-select": "^3.0.8",
    "react-slick": "^0.25.2",
    "react-toastify": "^5.5.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.8",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "showdown": "^1.9.1",
    "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^6.8.0",
    "eslint-loader": "^3.0.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.18.3",
    "url-loader": "^3.0.0"
  }
```

I have tried removing node_modules and reinstalling again as well, doesnt seem to fix the issue.

Following is my project structure

[image: Project Structure]

Comment: did you start it with yarn/npm dev?

Comment: yes I m using yarn dev

Comment: What do you try to change?

Comment: @felixmosh When ever I m updating my js file or style file, it doesnt reload the latest changes.

Comment: Ham, long shot, maybe it is related to the fact that your pages contains upper case folders?

Comment: well that works @felixmosh

Comment: WOW!?  glad it worked :]

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Got help from @felixmosh. There was issue because of my folders were case was not matching route case. Fixed the issues by changing folder name to route names.

Comment: Yes, the casing matters inside of the `/pages` directory. If you try to hit `/users` and your directory structure looks like `pages/Users`, the page will render, but will not hot reload. Hope this helps someone

Comment: @StephenBurke is this documented somewhere?  I could only find mention in a GitHub thread, but this is the kind of thing that should be featured in bold letters within the API docs.

Comment: @bsplosion agreed, I only found this solution by trial and error :)

Comment: I too was facing this issue, as my component/<filename> was in"kebab case" and the function name had the first letter in uppercase

Answer (score 30):

I just solved this problem by deleting folder ".next" and then closing terminal, and run `npm run dev` again.

Answer (score 11):

Sometimes, when you accidentally name a component starting with a lowercase and then later changes to capital letter, next cache will still consider the older name and won't count it as a normal component.
The easiest solution is to copy the contents of the components, delete the file, and create one with a proper component name.

Comment: This was my issue cheers

Comment: This was the case for me too, thanks a lot.

Comment: This was it in my case

Comment: This is exactly what happened to me as well. Thank you for that

Answer (score 5):

in my case hot reload didn't work because there was assetsPrefix in my next.config.js. You can remove or change them to "/" in the development mode and everything will be as expected.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, it wasn't working on Chrome. But it was working on Edge browser. And funny enough... even on a guest chrome window.

So all I had to do was...

> **Clear the cookies and hard refresh.**

Comment: For me removing .next folder and then running on Safari worked.

Answer (score 2):

for me the solution was wrong in importing the the header component
`/src/sections/header.tsx`
in my `/src/pages/index.tsx` i was importing it like this
`import { HeaderSection } from '../sections/Header';`
all what i did to fix this issue is to make the import like this
`import { HeaderSection } from '../sections/header';`

## note

both the projects will work fine but with the first one the Hot reload will not work until you re run your dev server

Comment: It was the same case with me too, but in case of importing css

Answer (score 1):

I had to go to package.json remove `react` and `react-dom` and re add them with yarn add.

Answer (score 1):

Force audit fix worked for me. Don't know the exact reason, might be some conflicts between dependencies.

Steps

1)Run this command in your next project directory.
**npm audit fix --force**

Answer (score 1):

the problem is naming component files , make sure for route folders you are using page.js and lower case to all files in them, make sure the component name is uppercase, after doing all this terminate your server close your code editor and delete your .next folder because next had cache those previous names, open the code editor and run the server again . it will work

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else that encounters this problem and is using WSL, hot reload does not seem to work if your app is sitting on one of your Windows volumes. You can work around this by moving the entire app to one of your WSL volumes. (i.e. make it a subdirectory of `/home/src` or the like)

This does present a new problem, which is now your Windows system has to be able to see your app's folder to make changes. There are a number of ways to do this, but if you're using VS Code you can connect directly to WSL from inside the IDE.

Answer (score 1):

I had `Disable Javascript` in my Chrome inspector

Answer (score 0):

For people *NOT* using modules and using **Typescript paths**.

For my setup, I just like having general `.scss` files

So, in my `_app.tsx`

I add `Styles/index.scss`

Then, in my `index.scss`

I add my `@import '~Styles/flex.scss'`

take note of the `~`

this was required for it to work with hot reloading.

Answer (score 0):

Wrt to Next js version 10+ and in addition to Pranay's answer, make sure your routes case matches the case of the folder.

Also, I noticed the component name has to start with the upper case. If your file name is `dashboard.jsx`, the component name should be `Dashboard`.

```
// home/dashboard.js

const Dashboard = () => {

....

}
export default Dashboard
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that in the layout.js you return something like this
`return ( <html lang="en"> <body> <Navbar /> {children} </body> </html> );`

IT wasn't working for me untill i added the html and body tags.

Answer (score 0):

in my case it was working on both chrome and safari, but not on brave, just tried toggling between brave shields for localhost  and shockingly , its only working when the brave shields are on for localhost! :O

Answer (score -1):

Oh for the love of All!

I just realised that my hot reload of imported component was not working because of the CAPITAL LETTER OF THE FOLDER!?!?

I did this:

```
src/components/MyTopBar/MyTopBar.tsx
```

so BOTH the name of the folder and the name of component were starting with capital letters. I imported component - it showed up when i did yarn dev and all rendered ok but when i changed anything in the MyTopBar.tsx the change would NOT WORK - no reload / no refresh. Had restart yarn dev to see changes.

So when i changed to this:

```
src/components/myTopBar/MyTopBar.tsx
```

the folder name inside the components starts with small letter and inside it the component name starts with capital letter.

ALL IS WORKING FINE! Hot reloads / styled-components changes / content changes - all is now shown properly.

Hope it helps! Did i completely forgot some basic rule of naming or is it next.js thingy?

Answer (score -1):

I'm running on Next js 13, I did follow the right naming conventions for the app src folder and component folders but **hot reload** didn't work at all. I was running on **next: "13.4.19" version**. after searching everywhere and countless deletion of the .next folder the solution that worked for me was to change the version to **"13.9.4"**.

Answer (score -2):

you need to run `npm run dev` instead `npm run start`

Comment: Why? Your answer should contain some information on the difference between the two and why one will work when the other doesn't

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score -3):

if your component is something like Test.jsx convert it to TestComponent.jsx
should not be jest one word , use it like this

Comment: "_use it like this_" - like... what?