# Using Next.js dynamic url stops hot reloading

Tags: reactjs, url, dynamic, next.js

I'm using Next.js dynamic url and after adding [id].js my hot reloading stoped even I should stop npm and restart it. does any one have any idea about my problem?[image]

Comment: Open an issue in the official repo: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to avoid using capitalized letters in your `pages` folder. Try changing `Projects` folder to `projects`. You can refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61033562/hot-module-reload-is-not-working-on-my-nextjs-app)

Comment: by changing that I get this error :./pages/projects/[id].js
Module not found: Can't resolve './node_modules/next/router', then I upgraded my yarn to 2.0.0 but nothing happened.

Comment: actually problem solved with using project instead of Project and after that upgrading my yarn and removing node modules and re installing it. using this type of address : 'next/router' instead of 'node_modules/next .... ' .