# hot module reloading not working for file changes in child components of _app.js (nextjs)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

i have tried out multiple options including reinstalling modules, changing next.config.js as follows

```
assetPrefix: process.env.NODE_ENV==='production'?"":"/"
```

and also i have tried
[hot reload not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61033562/hot-module-reload-is-not-working-on-my-nextjs-app)

I also went through [this closed issue on github](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/30576),which suggested correctly naming file names, but in nextjs, the _app.js file is always booting up irrespective of the route, so i placed some component inside it to check for login authentication. the logic is that if i am logged in the index.js would come up or else other component that is present on the route. this way i could prevent private routes to be opened.

Also If I see the compiler logs i am able to see

```
compiling /_error(client and server)
```

which is not clear to me at all. How to be able to log the details with this error as i think this might one of the reason behind hmr not working.

Comment: one more specific question is that how to log every step of compilation in nextjs