# why is React not auto updating when i change code

Tags: reactjs

```
import styles from '../styles/Home.module.css'

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <h1>Hello</h1>
    </div>
  )
}
```

I have tried using Next.js , React , Vite with react and none of them update when I update the code unless I restart the react server how can I fix this?

Comment: This might help 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61033562/hot-module-reload-is-not-working-on-my-nextjs-app

Answer (score 0):

I used Powershell instead of wsl and it fixed the issue.

the problem is I don't know how to use wsl without the issue coming up.