next.js not live showing changes on local host server. not hot reloading
Next.js hot reload not working.
I just created a Next project with npx create-next-app@latest 
But when I try to make changes to the code, it doesn't hot reload.
directory structure
I tried deleting the .next folder and npm run dev again to start the local server, but it is still not hot reloading.

Does any of these cases matches with your probllem?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61033562/hot-module-reload-is-not-working-on-my-nextjs-app
